# StackOverFlowException in file with two classes

Tags: c#

The following code generates StackOverFlowException. The question is why? It looks legit to me...

```
using System;

namespace learning
{

    public class TestClass
    {
        private String name;

        public String Name
        {
            get => Name;
            set => name = value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TestClass e = new TestClass();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried removing the namespace learning {...} but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Your property is returning itself:

```
public String Name
{
    get => Name;
    set => name = value;
}
```

Instead, it should return the field `name` (case sensitive):

```
public String Name
{
    get => name;
    set => name = value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are making a recursive call to the property `Name`, target the field instead i.e `name`

```
public String Name
{
    get => name;
```

This is a perfect reason why i like to underscore my fields names `_name`, The other being so i don't have to use `this.name` in methods or constructor